# Summing a total from multiple sales into a single column

Tags: sql-server

I'm having issues with what I believe should be a simple problem in SQL Server 2017. I need to show the total sales price for a given sale. This is what I have written (note I deleted the totalprice sum formulae because it returned an error) :

```
USE [Antiques]
GO

DECLARE @TotalPrice INT

SELECT 

Sales.SaleNo,
Sales.SalesDate,
Customers.FirstName,
Customers.LastName,
Products.Price,
@TotalPrice AS TotalPrice

  FROM   

  Customers JOIN Sales ON Customers.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
            JOIN SalesProducts ON Sales.SaleNo = SalesProducts.SaleNo
            JOIN Products ON SalesProducts.ProductID = Products.ProductID

            WHERE (Products.ProductID = SalesProducts.ProductID) 


GO
```

This is the result: 
[image]

Even if I remove the item price (which I have just put in temporarily and won't be in final code) there are still multiple lines per sale (1 for each item in the sale). Have I used the wrong joins? How can I get it looking like this: 
[image]

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried so many ways of using the Sum function and Group By and failing. (Note: this has to be a basic query and not a stored procedure unfortunately)

Comment: Where is the sample data and insert that in text format rather than in image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you're not too far away. I'd move the grouping in a derived table and join that, to get the totalprice.

```
SELECT sales.saleno,
       sales.salesdate,
       customers.firstname,
       customers.lastname,
       x.totalprice
       FROM sales
            INNER JOIN customers
                       ON customers.customerid = sales.customerid
            INNER JOIN (SELECT salesproducts.saleno,
                               sum(products.price) totalprice
                               FROM salesproducts
                                    INNER JOIN products
                                               ON products.productid = salesproducts.productid
                               GROUP BY salesproducts.saleno) x
                       ON x.saleno = sales.salesno;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was after. I didn't even think of making a derived table, I'm going to practise those now because I still get confused when trying to visualise and plan joins. Wish I had more rep so I could give some away.